# OpenGL how to render background

Tags: opengl, background, render

Hi I am doing an assignment and can't figure out how to render a background. 
I've drawn the triangles and every thing renders to the screen ok but it always becomes the foreground and blocks everything else from view.

Here is my code for rendering the back ground.

```
void render(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(bgShaderID);
    glBindVertexArray(bgArrayID);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // draw everything else

    glutSwapBuffers(); 
    glFlush();

}
```

In my vertex shader I have the following:

```
in vec3 a_vertex;
in vec3 a_colour;

out vec3 fragmentColor;

void main(){    

    gl_Position =  vec4(a_vertex.xy, 0.0 ,1);
    fragmentColor = a_colour;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have the `GL_DEPTH_TEST` enabled. I don't know what projection matrix and z values you use for drawing your foreground objects, but

```
gl_Position =  vec4(a_vertex.xy, 0.0 ,1);
```

is setting clip space z of the background to 0. Assuming a perspecitve projection, this is redicolously close to the front plane. Assuming some prthographic projection, this is still in the middle of the depth range.

You could of course try to set z=1.0 to set it to the far plane in the shader. However, since you draw the background first, you might be better off just disabling the `GL_DEPTH_TEST` (or disabling depth writes via [`glDepthMask(GL_FALSE)`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDepthMask.xhtml))  temporarily during drawing of your backgorund.